# ¿Cómo verificar si un numero es divisor de otros cuatro números?

Tags: c++

El usuario ingresa un número inicialmente, el cual se definirá como divisor *(d)*, después ingresa cuatro números más.

> Verificar si *d* es divisor de cada uno de esos cuatro números ingresados.

En caso de serlo, mostrar esos números en pantalla, con el enunciado *d es divisor de:*

**Ingreso estos 4 números y también ingreso "D"**

Al momento de ejecutar el programa, escribo tres divisores de *D*, pero suponiendo que el cuarto divisor **NO** es divisor de *D* por qué en la respuesta siempre me sale que sí es divisor

Cuando este debería de salir que NO es

```
//Divisores de un número

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int N1,N2,N3,N4,D;
    
    cout<<"INGRESE D"<<endl;
    cin>>D;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL PRIMER NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N1;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL SEGUNDO NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N2;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL TERCER NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N3;
    cout<<"INGRESE EL CUARTO NUMERO"<<endl;
    cin>>N4;
    
    if(D / N1 / N2 / N3 / N4 == 0){
        
        
        cout<<N1 <<N2 <<N3 <<N4 <<"SON DIVISORES DE "<<D<<endl;
        
        
    }
    else{
        cout<< N1 << N2  << N3  <<N4  <<"NO SON DIVISORES DE "<<D<<endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada recuerda que el divisor es el que divide (el numero que va debajo) o sea que te interesa saber si N1/D no tiene residuo (division exacta)

Lo anterior se escribe así `N1 % D == 0` en C++ y tambien en C y C#

Asi mismo se usan operadores lógicos para preguntar varias cosas a la vez.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el programa que mencionas entonces debe cumplir cuatro condiciones al tiempo (usando el operador lógico `AND --> &&`)

```
if ((N1 % D == 0) && (N2 % D == 0) && (N3 % D == 0) && (N4 % D == 0)){
    cout<<D<<"ES DIVISOR DE LOS CUATRO NUMEROS"<<D<<endl;
}
else{
    ....
}
```

Te invito a leer sobre operadores logicos y matematicos de C++ y otros conceptos sobre los condiciones y de paso ciclos, dado que parece que estas resolviendo tareas.